# How to add file in zip and remove it using python?

Tags: python, flask, zip, file-permissions, read-write

I am trying to create one flask application to document management, where all documents will present in one folder. when user wants to download documents I will create one zip of all documents and that zip file will return using send the file.

```
def createZip(user_sub, files):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Document.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for file in files:
        zipf.write(user_sub + file)
        print("file zipped ")
        os.remove(user_sub + file)
        print("file deleted ")
    zipf.close()
    print("--------zip file created and moved to trash--------")
    return None
```

above code of creating zip and next is of flask route

```
@app.route('/adminAction', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def adminAction():
    status = request.args.get("act")
    if status == "print":
        db.createZip(user_sub, files)
        return send_file('Document.zip', mimetype='zip', attachment_filename='Document.zip', as_attachment=True)
    else:
        db.deleteFiles(user_sub)
        return redirect("admin")

    return render_template("AdminDashboard.html", files = files)
```

Giving error of permission after printing some line

```
file zipped 
file deleted 
file zipped 
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 11:55:53] "GET /adminAction?act=print HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raviraj Pawar\PycharmProjects\AmirBusiness\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
File "C:\Users\Raviraj Pawar\PycharmProjects\AmirBusiness\DatabaseHelper.py", line 101, in createZip
    os.remove(user_sub + file)
    PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Raviraj Pawar\\PycharmProjects\\AmirBusiness\\Uploaded Documnet\\amirkanai1\\paddy-20200621-060101.pdf'
```

**EDITED PART:-**
changed createZip function and created a new function for deleting a file were added 10 sec sleep time. User has to get a request for performing an operation.

```
def createZip(user_sub, files):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Document.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for file in files:
        zipf.write(user_sub + file)
    zipf.close()
    print("--------zip file created and moved to trash--------")
    return None


def deleteFiles(user_sub):
    time.sleep(10)
    for filename in os.listdir(user_sub):
        os.remove(user_sub + filename)
        print("deleted ", filename)
    return None
```

Any help, a suggestion will appreciate.

Comment: I think you should not delete the file immediately after sending it.  try like this, after sending the file start a new thread, in that thread wait for at least 5-10 sec by using sleep(10) and then delete the file, because maybe OS using that file while you are deleting it.

Comment: this not working. I am editing my post to get you a clear picture.